# jython commands in WSadmin

Tags: jython

Can anyone tell me how to exit from jython scription on exception.I tried using exit/quit commands but it throws me error.In the below command am expecting to comeout of scripting on test = ''

### command

```
-c "print (sys.version); test='';" +               
-c "if (test == 'project'):" +                     
-c "print test" +                                  
-c "else:" +                                       
-c "exit"
```

### output

```
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "exit"; exception information:   
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:                      
Traceback (innermost last):                                            
  File "<input>", line 1, in ?                                         
NameError: exit
```

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

The function to exit from a script is:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

So replace your exit with the code above.
If you still have problems, let me know. :)

Have a nice day!